# find multiple total with multiple condition with one query in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my document

```
var trip = new Schema({
    unique_id: Number,
    is_trip_completed: Number,
    is_trip_cancelled: Number,
    is_trip_cancelled_by_user: Number,
    is_trip_cancelled_by_provider: Number,
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}
```

How can I get a result from a mongo query like

```
[
    {
        _id: null, 
        is_trip_completed: 20, 
        is_trip_cancelled: 48, 
        is_trip_cancelled_by_user: 84,
        .....
    }
]
```

which provides count of total record satisfied with different conditions?

Comment: Why fields `is_XXX` are numbers? Isn't it supposed to be a boolean? Please also add what you have tried and sample of document

Comment: yes it is boolean, i want to array as response define as above with specified conditions

Comment: var query = [
        {
            $group:{
                _id: null,
                "trip_completed": {
                    $sum: { $cond:[
                            { $eq: [ { "is_trip_completed": 1 }, 1 ] },
                            1,
                            0 ] } },"trip_cancelled_by_user": {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond:[
                            { $eq: [ { "is_trip_cancelled_by_user": 1 }, 1 ] },
                            1,
                            0 ]  }  }  }  } ]

Answer (score 4):

```
 var query = [
        {
            $group:{
                _id: null,
                "is_trip_cancelled": {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond:[
                            { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$is_trip_cancelled", 1 ] }, { $eq: [ "$is_trip_cancelled_by_provider", 0 ] }, { $eq: [ "$is_trip_cancelled_by_user", 0 ] } ] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    ]




result:

[ { _id: null,
    is_trip_cancelled: 27 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is $group stage which you should apply:

```
$group:
{
    _id: null,
    "trip_completed":
        { $sum: { $cond:[ {$eq: ["$is_trip_completed", 1]}, 1, 0] } },
    "is_trip_cancelled":
        { $sum: { $cond:[ {$eq: ["$is_trip_cancelled", 1]}, 1, 0] } },
    "trip_cancelled_by_user":
        { $sum: { $cond:[ {$eq: ["$trip_cancelled_by_user", 1]}, 1, 0] } },
    "is_trip_cancelled_by_provider":
        { $sum: { $cond:[ {$eq: ["$is_trip_cancelled_by_provider", 1]}, 1, 0] } }
}
```

It calculates sum of `{ $cond:[ {$eq: ["$field_name", 1]}, 1, 0] }` which has either `1` if `{$eq: ["$field_name", 1]}` condition was met, or `0` in other case. That gives you count of documents which met specified condition.